# How do I add more than one element to a menu in Wordpress in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Right now I have it so when you are logged in, the menu in the header displays a welcome message with the username of the logged in person. And if nobody is logged in, it displays "login". I have the following code in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_custom_menu_item');
function my_custom_menu_item($items)
{
    if(is_user_logged_in())
    {
        $user=wp_get_current_user();
        $name=$user->display_name; // or user_login , user_firstname, 
user_lastname
        $items .= '<li><a href="">Welcome '.$name.'</a></li>';
    }
    else
    {
        $items .= '<li><a href="">Login</a></li>';
     }
    return $items;
     }
```

How would I go about having another link in the menu that says "log out" next to the welcome message when logged in, and a "register" next to the "login" when not logged in?

Also, right now the welcome message and login elements are appearing in both the upper left corner menu and the main navigation menu. However, I only want it to appear in the upper left. How would I go about fixing this?

Link to the site I'm working on if it helps:  digitalenclave.net

Answer (score 0):

You could do something such as

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_custom_menu_item');
function my_custom_menu_item($items) {
    if(is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user=wp_get_current_user();
        $name=$user->display_name; // or user_login , user_firstname, user_lastname
        $items .= '<li><a href="">Welcome ' . $name . '</a><span style="margin-left: 10px;"></span><a href="">Logout</a></li>';
    }
    else {
        $items .= '<li><a href="">Login</a><span style="margin-left: 10px;"></span><a href="">Register</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;
}
```

However, you would need to add the URL of where the location of where each link should go to within each `href=""` attribute in the HTML lines.

I took a look at the site and to be able to set the links to the left part of the page you would want to add the following somewhere in the CSS of your page.

```
.row.logo-left {
    float: left ;
}
```